# Delete key-value pair from Hive map?

Tags: dictionary, hive, dml

I have a Hive table with two columns `score` and `name`, and `name` is `map<string, string>` of key-value pairs. My question is can I delete one of the key-value pairs based on `score` and `name.key`.

For example, I have a few rows in that table:

```
100 {"1": "A", "2": "B", "3": "C"} 
95  {"4": "D"} 
90  {"5": "E", "6": "F"}
```

Can I delete say `with where score=100 and name.key='2'` or something like this?

Any comment will be super helpful. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop ecosystem is not made for data update or delete in data.

work around

1  Move this data in different partitions and drop that partition.

or
  1 create a different table with same structure (OLD table)

2 Use insert into and populate the data .

3 Drop original the table.

4 Rename new table with old table name

Comment: See this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Delete But I'm not sure what to write in the where expression, since I want to delete based on the value outside of the map and the map key.